# How to exclude directories from search and "Recent" in Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: 18.04, gnome-activity-journal

There used to be a "Privacy" setting in previous versions of Ubuntu which allowed to exclude specified folders and applications from search and "Recent".
Is there that kind of option in Ubuntu 18.04, too?

Comment: Are you referring to the activity-log-manager?  You might need to installl that: ``sudo apt install activity-log-manager``.

Comment: Activity log doesn't seem to be working very well on 18.04, nautilus still displays the recent activity for me